# Translating messages on the front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to translate some default messages in a page that is rendered by the back-end, but I must do it in the front-end. Can't afford to spend the time doing internationalization.With that in mind, is this a good quick fix? I really do know this is not the best idea at all.

```
var language = navigator.language;

const translate = {
  download: {},
  success: {},
  invalidError: {}
};

translate["download"]["pt-BR"] = "Clique aqui para fazer o download";
translate["download"]["other"] = "Click here to download the file";
translate["success"]["pt-BR"] = "Obrigado";
translate["success"]["other"] = "Thank you!";
translate["invalidError"]["pt-BR"] = "Campo invalido";
translate["invalidError"]["other"] = "Invalid field";

function translateMessages(message) {
  return translate[message].hasOwnProperty(language)
    ? translate[message][language]
    : translate[message]["other"];
}

const message = translateMessages("invalidError");

console.log(message);
console.log(language);
```

Comment: Google Translate? https://www.dummies.com/education/internet-basics/how-to-install-google-translates-website-translator-plugin/

Comment: You think internationalization is gonna be an overkill? Because it would be the best approach for scalability reasons (I mean, today is just another language, but since tomorrow they might going for you to add another and another). Google Translate, as Erik pointed out acn be good, unless those who asked for the feature disagree with what's being displayed.

Comment: Why create an object like that? Just put everything into the object at once, much easier to deal with. It's no different than any other solution--it's always down to a map of keys to translation.

Comment: Not an overkill at all. The context here is a legacy project that needs a quick fix, since we dont have the time to internationalize it  Karuless. And Dave, I'm creating the object like that so I can access its properties using the string returned from navigator.language(e.g "pt-BR"). I can'nt do it so using the notation translate = { pt-BR: {} }, because hyphens are not a valid javascript identifier, like numbers etc

Comment: @IanGuimarães ... `{ 'download': { 'pt-BR': 'Clique...', 'other': 'Click...' } }` Then a similar wrapper function, but it's as simple as `translate[message][navigator.language] || translate[message]['other']`

Comment: I don't think that google translate will work in this case, since we ensure support to IE 9. Googling about found a bunch of problems related to it

Comment: @DaveNewton, Thanks!! You're wright, way easier!

Comment: I would change the order of the keys, I mean, put language on the top level and then translation keys and values:
`{'pt-BR': { download: 'Clique...' }, other: { download: 'Click...' }  }`
Most of the translation libraries (like i18next for example), use this format, so it will be easier for you to make a transition from this fix to a more robust solution later.

Comment: @SciFiThief Great!! Thanks ill do that!!